# I have trouble with php variable

Tags: php, variables

I have a little question about variables in php.
How can I make this possible??

```
<?php

echo $test;
$test = 'This is a test';

?>
```

I know that you could fix it with ease with

```
<?php
$test = 'This is a test';
echo $test;
?>
```

but I cant use it in my page in that way.

Can any one please tell me how I can have a variable after the echo??

Comment: Show your actual problem

Comment: PHP doesn't support pre-cognition.

Comment: `echo $test;
$test = 'This is a test';
$test = 'But this is different';` So what should your `echo $test;` display in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo getTest();
function getTest(){
    return 'This is a test';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Buddy.. It can't be Done.. How you can output a value of a variable when its not assign to it..

Its common sense..

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A variable has to be declared before it has a value.